# Rank categories by sum (Power BI)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to rank products for my dashboard. Each day, we store sales of products. In result we have this dataset example:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| product   | date       | sales |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| coffee    | 11/03/2019 | 15    |
| coffee    | 12/03/2019 | 10    |
| coffee    | 13/03/2019 | 28    |
| coffee    | 14/03/2019 | 1     |
| tea       | 11/03/2019 | 5     |
| tea       | 12/03/2019 | 2     |
| tea       | 13/03/2019 | 6     |
| tea       | 14/03/2019 | 7     |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 30    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 4     |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 15    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 10    |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

### My attempt

I actualy managed to Rank my products but not in the way I wanted it; In fact, the ranking process increase by the number of rows. for example, chocolate is first but we record 4 rows so coffee is ranked at 5 and not 2.

```
+-----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
| product   | date       | sales | sum | rank |
+-----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
| coffee    | 11/03/2019 | 15    | 54  | 5    |
| coffee    | 12/03/2019 | 10    | 54  | 5    |
| coffee    | 13/03/2019 | 28    | 54  | 5    |
| coffee    | 14/03/2019 | 1     | 54  | 5    |
| tea       | 11/03/2019 | 5     | 20  | 9    |
| tea       | 12/03/2019 | 2     | 20  | 9    |
| tea       | 13/03/2019 | 6     | 20  | 9    |
| tea       | 14/03/2019 | 7     | 20  | 9    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 30    | 59  | 1    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 4     | 59  | 1    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 15    | 59  | 1    |
| Chocolate | 11/03/2019 | 10    | 59  | 1    |
+-----------+------------+-------+-----+------+
```

`sum` field formula formula:

```
sum =
SUMX(
    FILTER(
         Table1;
         Table1[product] = EARLIER(Table1[product])
    );
    Table1[sales]
)
```

`rank` field formula :

```
rank = RANKX(
    ALL(Table1);
    Table1[sum]
)
```

As you can see, we get the following ranking:

- **1** : Chocolate
- **5** : Coffee
- **9** : Tea

### Improvements

I would like to transform the previous result into :

- **1** : Chocolate
- **2** : Coffee
- **3** : Tea

Can you help me improving my ranking system and get a marvelous 1, 2, 3 instead of this ugly and not practical 1, 5, 9 ?

If you don't know the anwser, help by simply upvote the question ♥

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, this is an easy fix.

If you look at the [documentation for the `RANKX` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax), you'll notice an optional `ties` argument which you can set to `Skip` or `Dense`. The default is `Skip` but you want `Dense`. Try this:

```
rank =
RANKX(
    ALL(Table1);
    Table1[sum];
    ;;
    "Dense"
)
```

(Those extra `;` delimiters are there since we aren't specifying the optional `value` or `order` arguments.)

Comment: thank you ! One of my mate sent me this solution : `CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[ sum ]);FILTER(Table1;Table1[ sum ]>= EARLIER(Table1[ sum ])))` but yours is better